# Don't execute next line until Process.Start is complete

Tags: c#

I'm writing a simple C# console application which opens up four instances of Windows Explorer and uses Pinvoke's `MoveWindow` to place them around the screen. My problem is that the `Process.Start` command seems to run too slowly, and the `MoveWindow` function cannot find the process unless I deliberately slow the program down. Here is my code:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "explorer",
    Arguments = location,  //Defined elsewhere (for testing just ".")
    UseShellExecute = false
});
int[] pos = GetPositions(position); //Little function which gets the positions I want for this window
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
IntPtr hnd = GetForegroundWindow();
bool ok = MoveWindow(hnd, pos[0], pos[1], pos[2], pos[3], false);
```

See how I'm having to `Sleep` for an (arbitrary) half second. It's not ideal, because I don't know the specifications of the machine it will be running on. It could end up being either inefficient on a fast machine or could break on a slower machine. Is there a more concrete way of waiting until a process has started where I don't have to arbitrarily wait for a set time?

---

Also, on a semi-related note, you may notice a bit of cowboy code which just gets the foreground window to grab the window I want moved. This is because I had an absolute mare trying to pick out specific Window Explorer processes. From what I can tell they just don't work the same way as anything else (like when I was testing with notepad or IE) and just passing a handle doesn't work. Anyone who's familiar with this problem, feel free to contribute, but if not don't spend any time on it - clunky as this solution is, it works, and for a little application I don't want to spend hours bashing my head against the keyboard trying to figure out the proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, you would be able to call `Process.WaitForInputIdle()` which waits for a message loop to be created and be up and running in the newly started process. However, this does not work with all applications (and most likely not with Windows Explorer).

A cheap trick is to poll for the main window of the process to be created ([source](http://dotnet-snippets.com/snippet/process-wait-until-mainwindow-was-created/5776)):

```
public static bool WaitForMainWindow(this Process process)
{
    while (!process.HasExited && process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }

    return !process.HasExited;
}
```

You might want to make this more robust by adding a timeout:

```
public static bool WaitForMainWindow(this Process process, uint timeout)
{
    var start = DateTime.Now;
    while (!process.HasExited && process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        if ((DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds >= timeout)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return !process.HasExited;
}
```

Comment: When I try this it just always returns false - I believe because the ```MainWindowHandle``` is always zero (as far as I can tell)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
while(!process.HasExited)
{
  //process running
}
//Done
```

Comment: The trouble is that, for whatever reason, the process starting and the Windows Explorer window being displayed happen separately, and if I were to do that the handle could not be found. Regardless, I don't want to do something *until* a process exits, I just want to do something once the visual display has loaded, which seems to run on a different timetable to the process itself with Windows Explorer.